# Is Custom Domain required in SF when implementing SSO where SF is the Service Provider?

Tags: single-sign-on, identity

I think My Domain is only required when SF is the IdP of a SSO solution and not strictly required when SF is the Service Provider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Salesforce is Service Provider then My Domain is **mandatory** to be setup. Otherwise SP initiated flow will not work.

Where as, if Salesforce is Identity Provider then it could nice to setup My Domain, IdP initiated flow will work perfectly.

> [My Domain](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=domain_name_overview.htm&type=5) is required before you can use these Salesforce features:

- Single sign-on (SSO) with external identity providers
- Social sign-on with authentication providers, such as Google and Facebook

Also, refer [Considerations for setting up My Domain and SSO](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000171244&type=1)

Comment: Am I right to assume my domain is only required for SP-initiated sso?  IdP SSO from third party portal to standard SFDC domain would still work. My Domain is required for setting up single sign-on. For inbound single sign-on requests, the subdomain enables deep linking directly to pages in the org. No changes are required for the identity provider. The Salesforce SAML endpoint (login.salesforce.com) continues to work for SAML and OAUTH requests, even if your org deploys My Domain and selects Prevent login from https://login.salesforce.com in the My Domain Settings.

Comment: You are correct